# find an equation of the curve $ \vec{c}(t) $in cartesian

Tags: curves

find an equation of the curve $ \vec{c}(t)$ in $cartesian$ coordinates and sketch its graph  $\vec{c}(t) = (t+4)\vec{i} +t^{2}\vec{j}$ ; $ t\in [1,3]$

How to start?

Comment: Hint: write $x=t-4, y=t^2$ and try to find an expression like $y=f(x)$

Comment: yea i did that before but i do not know what next, or how yo graph it @Chris

Comment: what did you get?

Comment: @sh.alzoubi If you did that before, you should have said that you did so in the body of your question so that we do not repeat information you already know. Please include all your thoughts about the problem and what you've tried in the body of every question you ask.

Comment: Do you know how to find $t$ from $x=t+4$?

Comment: The concept is the same as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0h4vlO0p9M).

Comment: @Chris On your first comment, I think you mean $x=t\color{red}{+}4$. This is a typographical error, correct?

Comment: Of course it's a typo, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

We have $\vec{c}(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ with $x(t)=t+4$ and $y(t)=t^2$. Therefore

$t=x(t)-4$, hence

$y(t)=(x(t)-4)^2$.

Your turn !